# How to find the next seed that keeps the sequence of random numbers going in C?

Tags: c, random

I have an assignment in which I have to program a M/M/1 queue with random arrivals and service times. My problem is this: My professor wants us to prove that the queue is working properly and generating the correct statistics (Wait time, Avg number of people in queue, etc) regardless of the seed that is used to initialize the random number generator.

That means he wants us to use seeds that will not generate sequences that overlap. For example: If I initialize the random number generator with seed X and it generates the sequence [3, 5, 9, 2, 0], the next seed Y cannot contain (and continue) this same sequence.
One suggestion he did give us was to simulate an entire run of the queue and, at the end, find a seed that will continue the sequence from the number it stopped. Lets say our run with seed X generated the same sequence as above and the next call to rand() would have returned the number 19. He wants us to find a seed Y that will generate 19 as its first random number and then continue from there since these sequences will not overlap

As another suggestion he mentioned that if you used the last number generated by rand() in your previous run as the seed for your next run, the first number would be the continuation of the previous sequence, but I was unable to reproduce that. I have written the following code as a test to see if this method works:

```
//Initialize the random number generator
srand(10);

int new_seed;

//Generate a small test sequence of random numbers
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    //Store the new seed for later use
    if(i == 3){
        new_seed = rand();
        printf("%d: %d -> new seed!\n",i, new_seed);
    }else{
        printf("%d: %d\n",i, rand());
    }
}

printf("\n");
//Reinitialize the number generator with the new seed
srand(new_seed);

//Generate another small test sequence of random numbers
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d: %d\n",i, rand());
}
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
0: 1215069295
1: 1311962008
2: 1086128678
3: 385788725 -> new seed!
4: 1753820418

0: 1008718395
1: 1489456950
2: 1335983464
3: 366125540
4: 20514025
```

Which is not what I was expecting. As per my professor's explanation, the second sequence should have started with the number 1753820418, as it was the last one of the previous sequence.
Is this correct? Is there another way of finding out which seed will continue the sequence of the previous seed in C?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: For a good quality PRNG, it is impossible to quickly find a seed that produces a given number. `rand` is a pretty crappy PRNG, but you are not supposed to be able to break it anyway, unless you have studied this specific subject, breaking PRNGs. So you can go ahead and try all possible seeds, or write your own PRNG which is easy to break.

Comment: The sentence “That means he wants us to use seeds that will not generate sequences that overlap” does not logically follow from the prior sentences. Using seeds that will not generate sequences that overlap does not suffice to provide the software is working properly. In fact, executing the program with various sequences only serves as a test of the software, not a proof (unless exhaustive, which seems unlikely). So the actual issue would seem to be that some reuse of sequences weakens the test.

Comment: But how the test is weakened by potential repetitions is unclear. Using different seeds will generally generate different sequences. The frequency with which a sequence will completely repeat in two different tests is small and not a significant factor. There does not seem to be any need to continue a sequence in a new test from where it left off in a prior test. Simply use a different seed.

Comment: @n.m.: What reason or proof is there that it is impossible to quickly find a seed that produces a given number? Random number sequences are not inherently required to have cryptographic properties such as irreversibility. Common encryption schemes could server as decent random number generators in the encryption direction but be reversible by using the decryption direction.

Answer (score 0):

When `i == 3`, you call `rand()` to get a random number, store it in a variable called `new_seed`.  However, the value returned from `rand` is *not* necessarily a seed value.  If you want it to be a seed, you need to make it one:

```
    new_seed = rand();
    printf("%d: %d -> new seed!\n",i, new_seed);
    srand(new_seed);
```

Then the next call to `rand` will return a new random number based on that seed.

Your professor is expecting the value returned from `rand` to be the same as the "seed" used to generate the next random value, but this is not necessarily the case.  Visual Studio uses a 32 bit value internally for `rand` but only returns 15 bits from the middle.

Comment: Maybe I was not really clear with my question, I apologize, but I did set the `new_seed` as a seed in between the `for` calls. Regardless, now that I think of it, it doesn't make much sense to be able to continue the sequence of a seed from a number generated by it right? If it were possible then any PRNG would be trivial to break, just a simple call to `rand`, set the value as the seed and off you go with the complete sequence. Perhaps I misunderstood what my professor meant. Are there any functions in C or C++ that are able to continue a sequence of numbers even after restarting the program?